# Form submit 2 arrays

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a form submit.

Form is select a task, then show several rows with checkbox and select with values 1-10

If checkbox is selected is need to add values from select into database.

this is PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'){   
    if(isset($_POST['submita'])){
        foreach($_POST['nota'] as $key => $value)
            if (isset($_POST['boxes'])){
                foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $key => $value2){
                    if(isset($value2)){

                        $nota = htmlent($_POST['nota']);
                        $box = htmlent($_POST['boxes']);
                        $task = htmlent($_POST['task']);


                        $db->insert(array(
                                    "task" => $task,
                                    "nota" => $value,
                                    "box" => $value2,
                                    ), 
                                "erp_notes");  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Select';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="<?=$row['id'];?>"></input>
<?=$row['name'];?>
<select name="nota[]" >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>

</select>
```

I try many time but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first `if` you have `=` when you mean `==`.

You haven't posted the entire HTML so I'll have to assume there is a `submita` element there that's being set.  Your best bet is to do `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you are actually getting, and then build your code to match.

Your code is incorrect because it loops over every `boxes` for each `nota`, when what I suspect you want is to just check the checkbox that corresponds to that element.
You probably want something more like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['nota']))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['nota']); ++$i)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['boxes'][$i]))
            $db->insert(array('task' => $task, 'nota' => $_POST['nota'][$i], 'box' => $_POST['boxes'][$i], 'erp_notes');
    }
}
```

Comment: i use your cod and works 50%. now is inserted each nota only for box checked but only once. Example Box1 - nota 1 and 2 ; box2 - nota 5, 7 and 8; box3 -7 and 9 . Now in DB need to be 7 rows, that it is but script arange nota and boxes so, box 1-2-3 and nota 1-2-5-7-8-7-9 and box1=nota1; box2=nota2, box3=nota5 nota7-8-7-9 has boxid=0

Answer (score 0):

i was edited cod , but work like in comment from first answer

PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){     
        if (isset($_POST['nota']))
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['nota']); ++$i)
            {
                if (isset($_POST['boxes'][$i]))
                    $task = htmlent($_POST['task_id']);
                    $db->insert(array(
                        "nota" => $_POST['nota'][$i],
                        "date" => time(),
                        "box" => $_POST['boxes'][$i],
                        "task" => $task
                        ), 
                        "erp_note");
    }   
    }   
    }

HTML

<form class="grid_12" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="<?=$row['id'];?>"></input><?=$row['box_name'];?>
<select name="nota[]" multiple><option value="">select</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select>
<input  name="task" type="text" value="<?=$row['task_id'];?>" style="display:none;">
</form>
```